# Notepad ++ - How can I replace a line using a column from next line

Tags: notepad++, regex

So the problem is that, I have a really huge file of clients and I need to do this:

> example1.1@hotmail.com
>
> example1@hotmail.com;12345

Became this:

> example1.1@hotmail.com;12345
>
> example1@hotmail.com;12345

Sometimes it needs to be executed multiple times, like this:

> example2.2@hotmail.com
>
> example2.1@hotmail.com
>
> example2@hotmail.com;12345

Replacing...

> example2.2@hotmail.com;pass12345
>
> example2.1@hotmail.com;pass12345
>
> example2@hotmail.com;pass12345

Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

Where's the pass come from the in the last example?

In any case, I'd personally do this in a python script, but if you're not up for scripting, you could do something in Excel.  Rough outline since I don't have Excel on this system . . .

1. Open the file
2. Use Text to Columns to split on the ;
3. Reverse the rows (insert a dummy column with the row number, and then sort on that one descending)
4. in a new column next to the one with the numeric codes, create a formula of the form:

   ```
   =if(isblank(C3),C2, C3))
   ```

Assuming that the numeric codes are in column C, and this new one is column D, then this formula for D3 checks if C3 is blank.  If it is, it gets the value from C2, otherwise it preserves the value from C3.

5. After this is done, copy and paste special so you have the values
6. Redo the sort in the proper order
7. Delete the dummy columns
8. Save this as a comma delimited file with ; as the separator (or build a new column that's `=A1&";"&B1`, and just copy/paste that column to a text file . . .